# SQL Select Count for Multiple Condition/Criteria

Tags: select, count, where-clause

This is the Table and Data I am using:

Table Name: Customer_Table

```
Column 1<Product>  Column 2<Region>  Column 3<Customer Status>
EB1                AUSTRALIA         CUSTOMER
PS2                NEW ZEALAND       CUSTOMER
EB1                AUSTRALIA         CUSTOMER
PS2                NEW ZEALAND       DUPLICATE
PS2                NEW ZEALAND       CUSTOMER
PS2                NEW ZEALAND       CUSTOMER
EB1                AUSTRALIA       
EB1                AUSTRALIA         DUPLICATE
EB1                AUSTRALIA         DUPLICATE
EB1                AUSTRALIA         DUPLICATE
```

What am I after?

I am trying to calculate a single value
where

> 1. Column 1 = EB1
> 2. AND COLUMN 2 = Australia
> 3. AND Column 3 Excludes all **duplicates** but counts nulls

The final result should be= 3

Comment: what DB are you using (Oracle, MySQL, SQLServer, Postgres...) ?

Comment: Ignoring duplicate rows, or "DUPLICATE" values (both give 3 records)?

Answer (score 1):

use

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM Customer_Table WHERE 
Column3 NOT IN ( 'DUPLICATE' ) AND 
Region = 'AUSTRALIA' AND 
Product = 'EB1';
```